# How to code the function drop without the prelude module in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, recursion

I want to write some prelude functions by myself in `Haskell` to understand it better and to exercise a bit with it. I already coded the `TAKE` function but I have some problems with the `DROP` function.

```
take1 :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

take1 _ [] = []

take1 0 _ = []

take1 n (x:xs) = x:take1 (n-1) xs 

-- Input: take 5 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] 

-- Output: [1,2,3,4,5]

--This is the take Function and its working.

drop1 :: Int -> [a] -> [a]

drop1 _ [] = []

drop1 n (x:xs) = x : drop1 (n+1) xs 

-- Input: drop 5 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10] 

-- Output: [6,7,8,9,10] 

-- It´s printing out the whole List and not the wanted result.
```

Comment: I'm afraid you're going to have to rethink your logic here. For one thing, you're automatically including the first element of the list (`x`), which you obviously don't want to do (if `n` is non-zero).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea of drop is to skip the `n` first items, so just **discard** them recursively until you reach *0*:

```
drop:: Int -> [a] -> [a]
drop _ []     = []
drop 0 xs     = xs
drop n (_:xs) = drop (n-1) xs
```

The important base case that you miss is `drop 0 xs = xs`, so if I have nothing to **drop** I just return what I got.
Also note that we decrement (`(n-1)`) not increment in the recursive call, otherwise you will never reach to the base case.

Comment: I would also highlight the fact that you replaced `n + 1` with `n - 1`.